# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl in wildfly-9.0.2.Final

Tags: java, ant, wildfly-9

Enviornment - AS@wildfly-9.0.2.Final,JDK - java version "1.8.0_66" , Building tool - ANT

A java file having following code has been configured as a module (module add --name=jaroneapi --resources=~/Downloads/jaroneapi.jar)
I think the classes which I need are all in the rt.jar from my JDK.

```
    package api.jarone.com.pojo;
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;
public class TestJarOneDetails {
public void getOperatorInfo() throws Exception{
    try{
        System.out.println(" Getting error while accesing CachedRowSetImpl java class in wildfly-9.0.2.Final,This
java class has been packaged in jaroneapi.jar. Now 1. Go to $WILDFLY_HOME/bin directory and invoke command ./jboss-cli.sh --connect
2. module add --name=jaroneapi --resources=~/Downloads/jaroneapi.jar");
        CachedRowSetImpl localCachedRowSetImpl = new CachedRowSetImpl();
      }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
  }
}
}
```

Exception logs

```
    10:54:00,343 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component ClientTestHelperBean for method public abstract java.lang.String client.test.ejb.session.ClientTestHelperLocal.getValueByParamName(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:184)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl
at api.jarone.com.pojo.TestJarOneDetails.getOperatorInfo(TestJarOneDetails.java:12)
at client.test.ejb.session.ClientTestHelperBean.getValueByParamName(ClientTestHelperBean.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl from [Module "jaroneapi:main" from local module loader @707f7052 (finder: local module finder @11028347 (roots: /wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base))]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
10:54:00,356 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
10:54:00,357 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:184)
10:54:00,357 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
10:54:00,357 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
10:54:00,424 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl
10:54:00,424 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at api.jarone.com.pojo.TestJarOneDetails.getOperatorInfo(TestJarOneDetails.java:12)
10:54:00,425 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at client.test.ejb.session.ClientTestHelperBean.getValueByParamName(ClientTestHelperBean.java:46)
10:54:00,425 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:54:00,425 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
10:54:00,440 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl from [Module "jaroneapi:main" from local module loader @707f7052 (finder: local module finder @11028347 (roots: /wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base))]
10:54:00,441 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
10:54:00,441 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
10:54:00,441 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
10:54:00,441 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
```

After searching I have done following 2 steps

1.Under modules/com/sun/rowset/main created a module.xml containing

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.sun.rowset">  
    <dependencies>  
        <system export="true">  
            <paths>  
                <path name="com/sun/rowset"/>  
            </paths>  
        </system>  
    </dependencies>  
</module>
```

2. Modified the module jaroneapi as following

module add --name=jaroneapi --resources=~/Downloads/jaroneapi.jar --dependencies=com.sun.rowset

But still following error occurred.

```
    11:10:44,543 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactoryException: Resource javax/sql/rowset/rowset.properties not found
11:10:44,549 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactory.lambda$initMapIfNecessary$79(SyncFactory.java:393)
11:10:44,550 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
11:10:44,551 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactory.initMapIfNecessary(SyncFactory.java:388)
11:10:44,552 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactory.getInstance(SyncFactory.java:557)
```

Why this error has been occurred? 
Is there something I'm missing or some modules I need to include here?  Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should not use classes started with "com.sun" directliy, because These are not part of the java API.

Comment: @Jens,Thankx for reply!!so how to resolve this problem!

Comment: Could someone help me find the missing piece?Waiting for reply!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this below dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>rowset</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ..I am not using maven building tool, so i modified configured module as--> module add --name=jaroneapi --resources=~/Downloads/jaroneapi.jar --dependencies=--dependencies=javax.sql.rowset...but getting another error -->org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: javax.sql.rowset:main

Comment: add this `com.sun.rowset.jar` to your build path.

Comment: ..I am not using maven building tool, so i modified configured module as--> module add --name=jaroneapi --resources=~/Downloads/jaroneapi.jar --dependencies=com.sun.rowset.jar...but getting same error -->org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: com.sun.rowset.jar:main