# How to use JDBC in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc

I can't start "Hellow World, JDBC" app.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        String databaseUrl = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/example";

        try{
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

1. [I know then the error in this string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFh32.png). JVM can't find and load class by name, but idea seen this class.
2. [I add mariadb connector as a jar lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sCdy.png). It means then idea will feed classpass to jvm when it compiling.

I also add `requires org.mariadb.jdbc;` in `module-info.java` , but I have the same error.
I've already tried creating new project. It's don't help me too. I really don't know why the JVM can't reached Driver class

Comment: What JDK did you tell IntelliJ to use for your project?  The CNFE is a surprise to me.  It's not the Maria DB driver class that's missing; it's a class in javax,sql package.  You should have that as part of the JDK.  Are you using Maven?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37130437/642706). You seem to trying to use [`RowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/module-summary.html) without an implementation.

Comment: Post text rather than images.

Comment: Try adding `requires java.sql.rowset;` to your `module-info.java`. However, given the MariaDB Connector/J driver doesn't seem to be modularized (otherwise it would have worked), I think you're better off not using a modular project, and instead reverting to a non-modular Java project (i.e. remove `module-info.java`).

Comment: @BasilBourque It looks more like MariaDB Connector/J is using some parts of javax.sql.rowset internally.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in JDBC driver for mariadb v.2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4. I solved this problem by simply downgrading to an older version 2.4.4